# send a simple variable from view to controller rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to send a simple variable from my view like: @data1 = "something" to my controller whitout a form or buttons, I want do it with another events like when "close any dialog window" and send it automatically to some method in my controller.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I think same question like other one. Please have a look [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672155/passing-parameters-from-view-to-controller

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that (and don't want to). The Model-View-Controller pattern assumes the Controller is providing data (Models) to the View. Once the `render` method has been called the View is sent to the client browser. If you want the view to send data back to the controller you'll have to rely on HTTP and use links, forms or Javascript/Ajax.

Comment: Yep, Javascript/Ajax seems to be what he is looking for