# Devise: Pass unconfirmed email address back to sign in page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When a user registers for an account in my Rails app, I'm using the default Devise behavior to send them a confirmation email.  On the website, after the user fills out the registration form, they are automatically redirected to the login page with an alert notice that they need to confirm their account via email:

> "Please confirm your acount via email."

I would like the alert to be more specific, like

> "A confirmation email has been sent to <%= confirmation_email%>.
>   Please click the link in the email to finish the registration
>   process!"

**How can I pass the unconfirmed email address back to the view?**

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that when you're creating the user, you're still saving the unconfirmed email address in your database when you create/save the user? If so, you should be able to call it the same way you call other variables in the view. Make sure they are defined in the associated controller and then call them up in the view with something like <%= @user.email %>.

Comment: thanks for your response.  looking at my devise registration controller, it automatically redirects to the sign_in user page.  I tried passing the email to this view as follows: sign_in user, :email => user.unconfirmed_email, but it doesn't seem like this parameter is sent.  Do you know how to pass a parameter to the sign in view?

Comment: You can pass the email through the params hash as one option if you really don't want to save the unconfirmed email (check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672155/passing-parameters-from-view-to-controller) for more details on the params hash). My original suggestion though was to save the unconfirmed email in the database (as this is the email that will likely be saved there anyways).

Comment: @scientiffic This approach wont work. Devise actually has an en.yml file which lists all the messages related to devise. It contains your confirmation message as well you need to somehow pass your users email to en.yml file

Comment: how do I pass a user to an en.yml file?

Comment: @scientiffic Needed to fix this in my app too but it was keep getting delayed so decided to fix it today :)

Answer (score 0):

Needed to override devise registrations controller create action with this code:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController 
  # POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    if resource.save
      # this block will be used when user is saved in database
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        # this block will be used when user is active or not required to be confirmed
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        # this block will be used when user is required to be confirmed
        user_flash_msg if is_navigational_format? #created a custom method to set flash message
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      # this block is used when validation fails
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

  private

  # set custom flash message for unconfirmed user
  def user_flash_msg
    if resource.inactive_message == :unconfirmed
      #check for inactive_message and pass email variable to devise locals message
      set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_unconfirmed", email: resource.email
    else
      set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
    end
  end
end
```

Then pass email variable in devise.en.yml file

```
en:
  devise:
    registrations:
      signed_up_but_unconfirmed: "A confirmation email has been sent to %{email}. Please click the link in the email to finish the registration process!"
```