# Set value in controller based on submitted value in text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp

First off. new to Rails, just learning.

What I'd like to do is on pressing my Submit button, pass what's in the text_field_tag and use that in my application_controller.

Here's my form structure:

```
<% content_for :title, "Home" %>
<h2>MailChimp API Login</h2>
<%= form_tag do %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:apikey) %>
  <p><%= submit_tag "Log In", :name => "apikey" %></p>
<% end %>
```

and my application controller:

```
require 'mailchimp'

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :setup_mcapi

  def setup_mcapi
    @mc = Mailchimp::API.new(params[:apikey])
  end
end
```

So I'd like to set @mc to whatever is in the text_field_tag(:apikey) input box. I'd also like to know how to process this when the user presses submit.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you gone through any Rails tutorials on how forms and controllers interact? See some of the guides at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/. Also, there are related questions on SO, such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672155/passing-parameters-from-view-to-controller

Comment: I have managed to change my submit_tag to the following: <%=submit_tag "Log In", :name => "apikey" %> and trying to do something to set the mc variable in the controller like this: @mc = Mailchimp::API.new(params[:apikey]) - although I don't think I've linked my home page to my controller correctly.